# The error states that createAppConbtainer is undefined and that it isn't a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, frontend, navigation-drawer

everyone, I am trying to create simple drawer navigation but it doesn't seem to recognize createAppContainer displaying this error message on the screen "(0, _reactNavigation.createAppContainer) is not a function.

```
(In '(0, _reactNavigation.createAppContainer)(navigator)', '(0, _reactNavigation.createAppContainer)' is undefined)

<unknown>
    App.js:46:34
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:331:6
<unknown>
    index.js:7
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:331:6
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:197:45
global code
    <unknown file>:0
"
```

I've tried commenting out some lines and searching on Google but no results

```
   import * as React from 'react';
    import { Text, View, Image, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
    import {
      createDrawerNavigator,
      createAppContainer,
      DrawerItems,
      SafeAreaView,
    } from 'react-navigation';



    class Home extends React.Component {
      static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Home',

      };

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>


          </View>
        );
      }
    }





    const navigator = createDrawerNavigator(
      {
        Home,

      },
      {
        // drawerType: 'back',
        // drawerPosition: 'right',
        // drawerWidth: 200,
        // drawerBackgroundColor: 'orange',

      }
    );

    export default createAppContainer(navigator);

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
        padding: 8,
      }
    });
```

Comment: it's working try to reinstall react-navigation and link it's module properly.https://snack.expo.io/@paraskorat/Zm9ybG

Comment: I've tried reinstalling it again but same error messages. Please, could you show me a step by step link of a solution that might work if possible? Thank you

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html refer this link.